# ERROR Error: This constructor was not compatible with Dependency Injection

Tags: angular, angular-services

What is wrong in this **service injection**? This error only appears in header.component.ts. I am stuck in this.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService
  ) {}

  isLoggedIn:boolean=false;
  imageUrl;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if(localStorage.getItem('authToken')){
      this.isLoggedIn=true
    }

  }

  logout() {
    this.userService.userLogout().subscribe((res)=>{
      localStorage.removeItem('authToken');
    });
  }

}
```

This is my *app.component.ts* file:

```html
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Also, I have added   `providers:[UserService]` in *header.component.ts*

This is my user service:

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from '../model/user.model';

@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root' 
})
export class UserService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient,
                private user:User,
                private avatar:string) { 
    }  

}
```

Comment: make sure `UserService` i added in `providers` array in the module where `HeaderComponent` is declared

Comment: `UserService` needs either the `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` decorator, or it needs to be listed in the `providers` of the module it resides in.

Comment: I tried adding **UserSerice** in **providers** but same error

Comment: `@Injectable({providedIn:'root'})` is there in **UserService**

Comment: If it's provided in root you don't need to provide it in your module. Please show your UserService.

Comment: **User-Service**  `import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from '../model/user.model';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,private user:User,private avatar:string) { }

}`

Comment: How is `private avatar: string` provided?

Comment: I have removed the code related to `avatar:string`

Comment: I have removed the header and footer component, and added that code in app.component ; This solved the problem